# Loop copying value in bulk data columns (tables)

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I have a query regarding make a copy within columns when facing a bulk data.

Basically I have a tables, that are repeatable.

Eaxch table starts from B-column and continues towards next 53 columns to BB column, then there are 3 empty column and next table starts from BF to EF columns,  and last one from EJ to HJ column.

Then I would like to copy for instance a B column, paste it in FN column, knowing that this is a leftmost part of my table. To copy another columns I have to know, that the distance is 53 between leftmost and rightmost column of the table (which are the same) and 56 between leftmost column of 1st table and leftmost column of 2nd table. 
Initially I counted the columns like 
COLUMNS(FN11:HN11) =53, that is a simple excel formula. Next I used this code:

```
Sub cols_UK()
Sheets("14").Activate
Range("A11:A4739").Copy
Range("FN11, HR11, JU11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B11:B4739").Copy
Range("FO11, HO11, HS11, JS11, JW11, LW11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

which obviously works, but the job is quite tedious.

As same as here:

```
Range("FM11, HQ11, JU11, LX11").Value = "1to10"
Range("FM479, HQ479, JU479, LX479").Value = "11to20"
Range("FM947, HQ947, JU947, LX947").Value = "21to31"
Range("FM1415, HQ1415, JU1415, LX1415").Value = "MONTH"
```

where I would like to put some values in columns being in some particular distance from each other.

Is some loop solution in case of columns?

Thanks & regards,[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Sub CopyTableInWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lStartColumn As Long
    Dim lStartRow As Long
    Dim lEndRow As Long
    Dim lSpacer As Long
    Dim lWidth As Long
    Dim lPasteColumn As Long

    'Set table size and spacing values
    lStartColumn = 2
    lStartRow = 2
    lEndRow = 100000
    lSpacer = 3

    'Determine width of table, set the column number to start the new table, then copy and paste
    lWidth = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, lStartColumn), ws.Cells(lStartRow, lStartColumn).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    lPasteColumn = ws.Cells(lStartRow, lStartColumn).Column + lWidth + lSpacer
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, 2), ws.Cells(lEndRow, ws.Range("B1").Column + lWidth)).Copy ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, lPasteColumn), ws.Cells(lEndRow, lPasteColumn + lWidth))
End Sub
```